# In a precise sense, Is Quorum considered more of a blockchain or a Distributed Ledger?

Tags: quorum

In a precise manner, Is Quorum considered more of a blockchain or a Distributed Ledger?

Answer (score 1):

Its a blockchain based on Ethereum. It may also be used as a distributed ledger, but as a technology and implementation its a blockchain.

Comment: Just to add: all blockchains are (also) distributed ledgers (vice versa is not correct) so the original question is a bit... unfruitful